# C++ - Modern way to implement JS's setTimeout

Tags: javascript, c++, multithreading, c++11, timeout

I am building an app where requests come in on a `zeromq` socket. For each request I want to do some processing and send a response, however if a predefined time elapses I want to send the response immediately.

In node.js, I would do something like:

```
async function onRequest(req, sendResponse) {
  let done = false;

  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!done) {
      done = true;
      sendResponse('TIMED_OUT');
    }
  }, 10000);

  await doSomeWork(req); // do some async work
  if (!done) {
    done = true;
    sendResponse('Work done');
  }
}
```

Only thing I'm stuck on right now, is setting in the timeout in c++. Don't have a lot of experience with c++, but I am aware there are things in c++11 that would let me do this cleanly.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::future` is what you are looking for, this can either be used with `std::async`, `std::promise` or `std::packaged_task`. An example with `std::async`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <future>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::future< int > task = std::async(std::launch::async, []{ std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5)); return 5; } );
    if (std::future_status::ready != task.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(4)))
    {
        std::cout << "timeout\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "result: " << task.get() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Note that the task will continue executing even after the timeout so you'll need to pass in some sort of flag variable if you want to cancel the task before it has finished.

Comment: Just for my understanding: here "task" represents the work that I'm trying to do, which I run async and wait for it to finish in 4 seconds? If it doesn't I print timeout otherwise I do whatever. Is this correct?

Comment: @user3690467 yes that's correct. In this case the work is just sleeping for 5 seconds and then returning 5 which will probably always timeout

Comment: This is great tested it out but now the only issue I see is that this would block the thread until work or timeout. In js the process would do other stuff while this was going on. Possible to achieve the same effect here? ( this might be a dumb question but just wondering)

Comment: Not directly, in a future version of the standard or the boost implementation there are continuations available which allow you to call `then()` on a future which would do what you want